# .dialog using buttons values

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

My aim is for the user to press a button, that will then open up a pop-up, where they can select one of two options, the code should then post the value of the original button clicked and the value of the button pressed in the popup to a javascript function. I am not entirely sure how to go about this and I have been playing around with .dialog, from Jquery.

```
$( ".showOptions" ).click(function(){
var $self = .showOptions.val();
is 'basicModal'
$( "#popup" ).dialog({
    modal: true,
    width: 465,
    draggable: true,
    buttons: {
            "Product Specification": function() {
                programselector("Product Specification", $self);
                 $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
            "Future Requirements Forecast": function() { 
                programselector("Future Requirements Forecast", $self);
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );


            }
        }

});
```

At the moment, the code just displays the popup. It isn't posting anything to the javascript function.

I have a feeling its a syntax error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update this:

```
var $self = .showOptions.val();
```

as

```
var $self = this.value;
```

and i think this is not needed: `is 'basicModal'` so you can remove it from there. Now the code would be like this:

```
$(".showOptions").click(function(){
    var $self = this.value;
    $( "#popup" ).dialog({
        // popup code as is
    });
});
```